# Selecting one record from two tables and multiple records from another table in ONE query

Tags: mysql, sql

As of now I have 4 tabels (that are relevant to this question); `pictures`, `photographers`, `models` & `picture_models`.

A picture can only have 1 photographer but multiple models. In the `pictures` table there is a `photographer_id` column, which can be found in the `photographers` table as well.

I want to select everything from the `pictures` table (with a specific `pictures.picture_id`), everything from the `photographers` table and then every model that have been assigned to the photo in `picture_models`. The `picture_models` table looks like this;

```
   Table: picture_models
   `picture_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `model_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
```

So every picture can have more than one record in `picture_models`. Back to my question.. is it possible to somehow select `models.*` together with the picture info and photographer info. As of now, my query looks like this;

```
    SELECT p.*,
           ph.*,
           COUNT(pv.vote) vote_count,
           SUM(pv.vote) vote_sum,
           (SELECT COUNT(vote) FROM picture_votes WHERE vote > 0 AND picture_id = ?) plus_votes,
           (SELECT COUNT(vote) FROM picture_votes WHERE vote < 0 AND picture_id = ?) minus_votes
              FROM pictures p
                 LEFT JOIN picture_votes pv
                    ON pv.picture_id = p.picture_id
                 LEFT JOIN photographers ph
                    ON p.photographer_id = ph.photographer_id
                 WHERE p.authenticated = 1
                    AND
                 p.picture_id = ?
```

Is it pointless/impossible to do what I want? Would it better to just do another query selecting all models exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this; you'll a copy of the picture/vote data for each model. This can be more efficient than doing two separate queries, especially if the number of models is low.

You might need to expand ph.* into individual columns, as without it there will be two photographer_id columns in the inner query, which may not be allowed. Also, a lot of databases would expect a `group by p.*, ph.*` with all the columns in the inner query. I think MySQL will let you away with it, though.

```
Select
    p.*,
    m.*
From (
    Select
        p.*,
        ph.*,
        count(pv.vote) vote_count,
        sum(pv.vote) vote_sum,
        sum(case when pv.vote > 0 Then 1 else 0 end) plus_votes,
        sum(case when pv.vote < 0 then 1 else 0 end) minus_votes
    From
        pictures p
            left join
        picture_votes pv
            On pv.picture_id = p.picture_id
            left join
        photographers ph
            On p.photographer_id = ph.photographer_id
    Where
        p.authenticated = 1 And
        p.picture_id = ?
    ) p
        left join
    picture_models m
        On p.model_id = m.model_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It definitely put me in the right direction. See my answer if it looks correct (it works by the way).

The amount of models will most often just be 1 and shouldn't be higher than 10.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Laurence's answer I was able to come up with this;

```
SELECT
    p.*,
    m.*
    FROM (
        SELECT
            p.*,
             ph.photographer_name,
             ph.photographer_website,
             ph.photographer_instagram,
             ph.photographer_facebook,
             ph.photographer_twitter,
             ph.photographer_googleplus,
            pm.model_id,
            COUNT(pv.vote) vote_count,
            SUM(pv.vote) vote_sum,
            SUM(CASE WHEN pv.vote > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) plus_votes,
            SUM(CASE WHEN pv.vote < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) minus_votes
        FROM
            pictures p
                LEFT JOIN
            picture_votes pv
                    ON pv.picture_id = p.picture_id
                LEFT JOIN
            picture_models pm
                    ON pm.picture_id = p.picture_id
                LEFT JOIN
            photographers ph
                    ON ph.photographer_id = p.photographer_id
        WHERE
            p.authenticated = 1
                AND
            p.picture_id = 1
        GROUP BY
            pm.model_id
        ) p
    LEFT JOIN
        models m
            ON p.model_id = m.model_id
```

Comment: I have grouped by pm.model_id in the inner query, is this correct?

Comment: The join to `picture_models` would be better in the outer query than the inner query. You wouldn't need a `group by` then.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Why is that by the way?